# Date Format using Angular and PrimeNG

Tags: angular, typescript, postgresql, primeng

New to angular, I am facing issue with formating date into UI..

My postgres DB has UTC format -eg **2021-09-23 08:41:35+00**. However when I render in UI its displaying as **2021-09-23 08:09:35** why there is difference and my database col datatype is timestamp with timezone.

Is it because of rendering UI?

I tried different ways like filter and all. Example:

```
                <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{col.updateTime | date:'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}

                       {{rowData[col.field] }}

            </tr>
```

UI doesn't display the specified format. I referred docs https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe. Not sure what is causing issue

Could you please help here?

Comment: If you don't pass the `| date`, what's the value of `col.updateTime`? it looks like somewhere you used Month twice instead of minutes. The angular code looks correct, so it might be before that, when reading from DB into the api.

Comment: Thank you for the quick support col.updateTime is one of the field from my api.A quick check I did ,still format is not changing
 ```  {{col.UpdateTime | date:'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:ss Z'}}

                       {{rowData[col.field] }}```

Comment: For reference ```<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
            <tr [pSelectableRow]="tes">
                <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{rowData[UpdateTime] | date:'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:ss Z'}}

                       {{rowData[col.field] }}

            </tr>
        </ng-template>```

Comment: In this comment you have something different than in the question. Lower case `m` is minutes and upper case `M` is months. But what I was really asking was for you to remove the `| date:` bit to see what you are really receiving from the API, it might be incorrectly coded there.